# R Overlap plot and histogram

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I need to plot an histograms and a graph in the same plot. I am having problem with ggplot2 becouse the dataset is very big.

What can I do?

Here an example

```
lambda=seq(0,1,length.out=100)
b1=lambda^2
b2=lambda^2+1 
b=cbind(b1,b2)
perc=rnorm(100)
matplot(lambda,b)
hist(perc)
```

Thanks for help :D

Sorry my question was not very clear.
I need to have the b and the histogram overlapped in the same plot.
Something like the plot in this slide.
[image]

This time i can not use ggplot becouse the dataset is too big and it takes to much times.

Comment: try adding `par(new=TRUE)` before the last line.

Comment: there's no ggplot2 here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not (yet) using `ggplot2`, and if you do you will need other commands to control layout, but what i think you want (for base graphics) is the `par` command.

```
lambda=seq(0,1,length.out=100)
b1=lambda^2
b2=lambda^2+1 
b=cbind(b1,b2)
perc=rnorm(100)
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
matplot(lambda,b)
hist(perc)
```

This yields the `matplot` as the top chart, and the `hist` as the second chart.

If you want side-by-side, use `par(mfrow = c(1,2))`.

As noted in the comments, if you want them on top of each other call `par(new = TRUE) in between the plot commands as follows:

```
matplot(lambda,b)
par(new = TRUE)
hist(perc)
```

Comment: You got it! par(new = TRUE) this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `subplot` command from the TeachingDemos package to add a new plot into an existing plot.